複数apiを呼び出すと401になる
Vue、laravelでSPA構成でwebシステムの開発をしております。
vueのとあるページから、5つほどAPIを呼び出しています。
時々なのですが、5つのうち1つだけ401エラーになって帰ってきます。（全て200で帰ってくる時もあります）
再現もしづらく、原因も不明で困っています。
アドバイスあればご教示いただきたいです。
補足
・Vueはlaravel配下のpublicに配置
・認証系はsanctum
・401が返ってくるときは、response_headerにset_cokkie:laravel_session=×××・・・が返ってくる。
※セッション名は、○○_web_sessionと設定しているので、401の時のレスポンスのセッション名がデフォルトのものに変わってしまっている。
